# Helpers in templates

Tags: javascript, meteor

Seeing if I can insert a helper into a template. Seems like I'm doing something wrong because you can't actually click the buttons in my program.

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>BubblePopper</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{loginButtons}}
  {{>home}}
</body>
<template name ="grid">

  <div id="container">
    {{#each buttons}}
      <button class="button" type="button"></button>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
 </template>

<template name = "home">
  <h1> Welcome to bubblePopper</h1>
  <p> Current Game Status:
    //this is the part I'm confused about is it ok to insert the grid helper into this
    //if statement in the template?
    {{#if game.active}}
      Game in progress. <a href="#" id="finishGame">Finish Game</a><br>
      <center>{{>grid}}</center>
    {{else}}
      {{#if game.finished}}
        Game done or another player left.<a href="#" id="newGame">Start a new game</a>
    {{else}}
      Waiting for a new player to login. Find a <a href="#" id="newGame">new game</a>
    {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
</p>
<p><strong> Current Game ID: </strong>{{game._id}}</p>
  <p><strong> Current Game Player Count: </strong>{{game.players.length}}</p>

  <p><strong> Current Game Active: </strong>{{game.active}}</p>


</template>
```

Client.JS:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Deps.autorun(function(){
    gameSubscription = Meteor.subscribe("myGames",Meteor.userId());
  });
  Template.home.game = function(){
    return gameCollection.findOne({current: true});
  };
  Template.home.events({
    "click #newGame" : function() {
      Meteor.call('newGame')
    },
    "click #finishGame": function(){
      var game = gameCollection.findOne({current: true});
      Meteor.call('finishGame', game._id);
    }
  });

  //was confused if I should just include buttons as a part of homes template
  Template.grid.buttons = function (){
    var list = [];
    for(var i=1; i<=64; i++){
      list.push({value: i});
    }
    return list;
    }

  Template.button.events({
    'click .button': function(ev) {
      $(ev.target).css('visibility', 'hidden');
      console.log("pop")
   }
});



}
```

I didn't include the server.js because it has nothing to do with any of the template helper relationship. Is this the right way to insert the grid? Also is it an error in my HTML that isn't allowing the buttons to be clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've mixed up the name of your template.  If it's the buttons in the `grid` template you're referring to, you need to change the line `Template.button.events({` to `Template.grid.events({` and then you should see the function being executed when a button is clicked.

Comment: heh literally just found the same error right as you answered the placement of {{> grid}} is ok though? @richsilv

Comment: I believe the `center` tag is no longer supported in HTML 5, so you should be putting `{{> grid}}` in a `div` with appropriate styling.  However, it looks fine in other respects.